# how to change the data in HTML table dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, dynamic-data, html-table

i hav a html tags stored in string and i want to load the table with the attributes which i given dynamically through program...

how to search the particular tags of the row and column of html and add the data to the attributes...

any help appreciated...

Thanks in advance......

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i hav first copied the html tags into string and then updating the date whenever i want ...

and then finally iam displaying ths dynamic html on to the web view to verify it....

Answer (score 1):

specify ID's or class names for HTML tags, and then update it using javascript or DOM.
ex:

HTML code:

Javascript Code:

document.getElementByid("tab1").value = Text in Box1 
 
document.getElementByid("tab2").value = Text in Box2

Comment: can u give me example ..i hav tags for html table view and i want to load the td values with data attributes

Comment: i am new to iphone..,i didnt use javascript until now

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I apparently can't comment so here's a more detailed explanation of Noddy Cha's answer.

To get values:

```
NSString * textBox1Value = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementByid(\"tab1\").value"];

NSString * textBox2Value = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementByid(\"tab2\").value"];
```

To set values:

```
NSString * ignoredString1 = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementByid(\"tab1\").value = \"%@\"", textBox1Value]];

NSString * ignoredString2 = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementByid(\"tab2\").value = \"%@\"", textBox2Value]];
```

Hope this helps.